# How to Solve the Problem of Route Matching

Tags: php, laravel

I configured two routes.

```php
Route::get("/team/{team}", "TeamController@show");
Route::get("/team/members", "TeamController@members");
```

However, when I want to access the route `/team/members`, I will be misguided to the route `/team/{team}`.

I tried to use regular expressions to restrict routing parameters in the boot method of `RouteServiceProvider`

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::pattern('members', "/^((?!members).)*$/is");
}
```

But it didn't work.

Using the postman access interface is still guided to the `/team/show` routing. So what should I do?

Comment: specific routes should go up, generic should go down. That's how laravel identifies the priority to choose from all routes.

Comment: What if you have a team called *members*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of your routes or `{team}` will also catch `'members'`:

```
Route::get("/team/members", "TeamController@members");
Route::get("/team/{team}", "TeamController@show");
```

Laravel always uses the first matching route.

Comment: Please note that you can't have a team called members this way as pointed out by @Nigel Ren

Comment: Of course. It's usually team id and id is encrypted with hashids.